# css not working in node reference view

Tags: views, nodes, entities

i am working on a development site. i am on hold because of two problems.

1. i have two content type A and B. i created a view for B content type. i used node reference in content type A  and call the created view so it display view fields rather than only title of nodes.   my problem is that when i start type any title in this field it display the options in autocomplete but it display white spaces, i add css but it is not working

   so the main question is css not working in node reference view result
2. i added a view in the same manner for a field. i want to add radio button on each result of view ,and when we click on radio button it's value copy in another field of content type.

Thanks , plz help me

Comment: I don't quite follow either of your questions. Maybe trying editing this and making it more clear what you mean by "white spaces" and "I add CSS".

Comment: i mean to say that suppose two fields are there in view firstname and lastname . these are displayed in view like 
firstname
lastname

but when this view is called as node reference in a content type field then it display with white space like
firstname



lastname

and i add css in style.css but it is not working for this space.


second one is that i used entity refernce in another field and call a view which has exposed filter , so after filtering it gives result, i want to add radio button at each result and want to copy selected result in another field added in the content type

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you get the regular node title to show up? Is the node title important? I am wondering if Automatic Entity Label could help you at all. Formerly Auto Node Title. https://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel‎
2. You may want to look at Rules and VBO. Creating a Rules Component "Action Set" and adding it to a Views Bulk Operations could handle this use case. Make sure you set the permissions properly when you create the Action Set (there is a collapsed field set called "Settings" when you edit a Rules Component that contains permissions settings for each Component)

Comment: thanks for answering

1. it will change the title of the node, but i don't want to change the title of the node, because it is used at many places. i want to add some fields with title when it is used as node reference in content type

2. http://awesomescreenshot.com/06b1qvhk43

please check the screenshot , it will explain my question better.

Thanks for your help